# add_FileTransferProgress crashes file transfer with Timeout error message for WinSCP (Powershell)

Tags: powershell, winscp, winscp-net

I have an script that simply download all the files from given ftp server (backup tool).

Everything works fine but it takes hours before complete so I've decided to add some progress info based on [WinSCP documentation](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_filetransferprogress):

```
function FileTransferProgress {
    param($e)
    if(($script:lastFileName -ne $Null) -and ($script:lastFileName -ne $e.FileName)) {
        Write-Host
    }
    Write-Host -NoNewline ("`r`t{0} ({1:P0})" -f $e.FileName, $e.FileProgress)
    $script:lastFileName = $e.FileName
}
$script:lastFileName = $Null


$sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions -Property @{
    Protocol = [WinSCP.Protocol]::ftp
    HostName = $ftpHostName
    UserName = $ftpUserName
    Password = $ftpPassword
}
...
$session.add_FileTransferProgress( { FileTransferProgress($_) } )
...
//start FTP session, open connection etc.
...

$transferOptions = New-Object WinSCP.TransferOptions
$transferOptions.TransferMode = [WinSCP.TransferMode]::Binary   
$session.GetFiles($hostFolderPath, ($targetFolderPath + "\*"), $False, $transferOptions).Check()

//message about finished trasnfer
...
```

Without my `$session.add_FileTransferProgress( { FileTransferProgress($_) } )` everything works fine but it takes a long time to see the finish message. With `add_FileTransferProgress` I don't get any files transfered and instead, after few minutes I always end up with:

> Error: Timeout waiting for WinSCP to respond

I've **not** changed anything else in the working code (only added `FileTransferProgress` and `functin FileTransferProgress`). I guess that program crashes when normally WinSCP would show "calculating directories" (before transfering files).

When I comment out `$session.add_FileTransferProgress( { FileTransferProgress($_) } )` everything works fine. Also, uploading of few files with `$session.PutFiles` works both with commented and un-commented line (it outputs the % progress for upload).

---

As `Martin Prikryl` requested:

I run this script from Start -> Powershell (as administrator) and then `cd` to where it is placed and `./script.ps1` (exactly the same way for both cases).

I've placed:

```
$session.SessionLogPath = "I:\Sites\Temp\TransferLog.xml"
$session.DebugLogPath = "I:\Sites\Temp\TransferDebugLog.xml"
```

before `$session.open(...)` but only the debug log (`TransferDebugLog.xml`) appeared (I post parts of it, because it's huge file):

```
Executing Assembly: WinSCPnet, Version=1.3.5.6958, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=...; Path: I:\Sites\WinSCP-5.9.2-Automation\WinSCPnet.dll; Location: I:\Sites\WinSCP-5.9.2-Automation\WinSCPnet.dll; Product: 5.9.2.0
Entry Assembly: 
Operating system: Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.14393.0
User: PolGraphic@...; Interactive: True
Runtime: 4.0.30319.42000
Console encoding: Input: Central European (DOS) (852); Output: Central European (DOS) (852)
Working directory: C:\Users\PolGraphic
Session.Open entering
...
Command: [open "ftp://...:***@... -passive=1 -timeout=15]
ExeSessionProcess.ExecuteCommand entering
ExeSessionProcess.ExecuteCommand leaving
ExeSessionProcess.ProcessEvent entering
  ExeSessionProcess.ProcessInitEvent entering
  ExeSessionProcess.ProcessInitEvent leaving
ExeSessionProcess.ProcessEvent leaving
ExeSessionProcess.ProcessEvent entering
  ExeSessionProcess.ProcessTitleEvent entering
    Not-supported title event [WinSCP]
  ExeSessionProcess.ProcessTitleEvent leaving
...
ExeSessionProcess.ProcessEvent entering
  ExeSessionProcess.ProcessInputEvent entering
    Scheduling output: [winscp> open "ftp://polgraphic...@..." -passive=1 -timeout=15]
  ExeSessionProcess.ProcessInputEvent leaving
ExeSessionProcess.ProcessEvent leaving
...
SessionLogReader.Read entering
  Opening log without write sharing
  Opening log with write sharing
  Log opened
  Skipping 0 nodes
  Read node 1: XmlDeclaration xml=version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"
...

  SessionLogReader.Read entering
    Read node 21: Element group
    Log contents has not changed
  SessionLogReader.Read leaving
  Session.GetFiles entering
  Session.GetFiles leaving
  SessionLogReader.Read entering
    Waiting for log update and dispatching events for 50
    Waiting for log update and dispatching events for 100
    Waiting for log update and dispatching events for 200
    Waiting for log update and dispatching events for 400
    Waiting for log update and dispatching events for 800
... //lots of "waiting for log update"
    Waiting for log update and dispatching events for 800
    Waiting for log update and dispatching events for 800
  SessionLogReader.Read leaving
  ProgressHandler.Dispose entering
    Session.DisableProgressHandling entering
    Session.DisableProgressHandling leaving
  ProgressHandler.Dispose leaving
  ElementLogReader.Dispose entering
    ElementLogReader.ReadToEnd entering
      SessionLogReader.Read entering
        Waiting for log update and dispatching events for 50
      SessionLogReader.Read leaving
    ElementLogReader.ReadToEnd leaving
    Swallowing exception
  ElementLogReader.Dispose leaving
Session.GetFiles leaving
Session.Dispose entering
  Session.Cleanup entering
    Terminating process
    Command: [exit]
```

Comment: 1) How do you run your PowerShell script? 2) Enable both session and debug logging (`Session.SessionLogPath` and `Session.DebugLogPath`) and show us the logs.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Hi, I've updated my question to answer your requests.

Comment: So you run the script in a normal PowerShell console window? I just cannot reproduce your problem. I've used your exact script (or course modified to make it work). It just works. The same build of Windows 10. After how many files does it fail? Isn't the code you have posted missing some important piece?

Comment: Does it hang fail on the same file always? (maybe some big file?) Or is it random? Did you try setting longer `Session.Timeout`? Do it help? Can you also try to remove both `Write-Host` calls from the `FileTransferProgress`? Does it help?

Comment: It fails for any ftp account & files I choose. Yes, the files together (that I want to download with `getFiles` are quite large). But they download without problem when progress is disabled. I guess script fails before even single file has been downloaded (on the stage analogical to "calculating" in WinSCP). I've removed `Write-Host` but without luck. Same for longer `Session.Timeout`.

Comment: But you wrote "Also, uploading of few files with `$session.PutFiles` **works** both **with** commented and **un-commented line (it outputs the % progress for upload)**."

Comment: Show us your exact script (except for credentials of course) + Change session log file extension to `.log` to get it generated. + Upload a full log files (XML and session) somewhere and post a link.